# KDE causing sound card to pop on startup

Tags: linux, audio, kde

I have just installed Kubuntu (Alienware M17x R4). Things generally seem fine but when it starts up the volume is at 100% by default for a moment until the volume control applet launches and remembers where it should be.

The login sound is turned off but there is a pop from the speakers every time I log in. I assume this is because of the high default volume.

Can I lower the default volume, or is there another way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the below command in your `/etc/profile`:

```
amixer set Master 40%
```

then save `/etc/profile` and reboot your system to test it.